# Strange effect when sum of the column width is larger than 12 in Bootstrap3?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

The codes can be viewed at

http://www.bootply.com/LUNqVTU2nj

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3" >
      <img class="img-square" alt="140x140" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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" data-holder-rendered="true">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3" >
      <h2> First </h2>
    </div>
      <div class="col-md-3" >
      <img class="img-square" alt="140x140" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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" data-holder-rendered="true">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3" >
      <h2> Second </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <img class="img-square" alt="140x140" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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" data-holder-rendered="true">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3" >
      <h2> Third </h2>
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

As can be seen in Bootply, the third image are not rendered at the correct place..

I thought it is wrong because a row can't contain columns whose total width is larger than 12, but on Bootstrap3 official sites, I saw codes like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8">.col-xs-12 .col-sm-6 .col-md-8</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">.col-xs-6 .col-sm-4</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">.col-xs-6 .col-sm-4</div>
  <!-- Optional: clear the XS cols if their content doesn't match in height -->
  <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">.col-xs-6 .col-sm-4</div>
</div>
```

Is this wrong? If not, why can't my codes work..

Moreover, is it possible to write all columns (for example, 30 columns) in one row and expect bootstrap to layout them correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is OK and a row can content more than 12 cells (a gallery for example) but your problem is that your divs has not the same height and you need to apply a "reset". To avoid this problem you need to insert a div class clearfix when you reach 12 cells.

I mean, in your example:

```
...
<div class="col-md-3">
    <h2> Second </h2>
</div> 
<div class="clearfix visible-md-block visible-lg-block">
...
```

Doc about Bootstrap clearfix: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets.

Also you could add javascript to apply same height to all your cells.

Comment: Sorry, i thought you were using md viewport. Try: <div class="clearfix visible-md-block visible-lg-block"></div> (i have edited my previous comment)

Answer (score 0):

```
.col-md-3{width: 25%;}
.col-sm-4{width: 33.3333333%}
```

So obviously only 4 elements could be contained in a single line, while you've placed 6. You can use class `.col-xs-2` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever code you have seen on bootstrap site is correct, but meaning is different. In a row only 12 columns are there, i think you are telling about xs having addition (xs-12 and xs-6) but meaning is that when you make it as xs then xs-6 will go to next line as shown in screen show, so use only 12 columns[image]s in row

Answer (score 0):

It's because in the example Bootstrap code you've posted they use different classes for different viewport sizes. Also anything over 12 will just "stack up".

So for example in this particular row:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">.col-xs-12 .col-sm-6 .col-md-8</div>
   <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
</div>
```

The `md` viewport adds up to 12 and will stay within one row with a size of 8 and 4.
The `xs` viewport adds up to 18 and 2 rows will be created where they stack up, where the first row will be 12 and the second will be 6.